# Achieve functor overloading through composition

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Given some existing functors:

```
struct incr {
    int operator()(int x) const { return x + 1; }
};

struct rep_str {
    std::string operator()(const std::string& s) const { return s + s; }
};
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve something like this:

```
auto f = overload<incr, rep_str>();
f(1);        // returns 2
f("hello");  // returns "hellohello"
```

Multiple overloads may look like:

```
auto f = overload<fa, fb, fc, ...>();
// or...
auto g = overload<fa, overload<fb, overload<fc, ...>>>();
```

I'm thinking maybe use SFINAE with `std::result_of_t` or something like that, but haven't figured out how.

Comment: How would composition of 3 overloads work with this syntax? `overload< X, overload< Y, Z > >` ? or `overload< X, Y, Z >` ?

Comment: @XerenNarcy I think both designs can work. `overload<X, overload<Y, Z>>` looks like nested pairs to me, while `overload<X, Y, Z>` reminds me of tuples (so that we cat do `overload_cat` or something like that).

Comment: There is even a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0051r0.pdf) to get something like that into the standard. It wasn't ready for C++17, but it is on track for C++20. There is also a [reference implementation].(https://github.com/viboes/tags/blob/master/include/yafpl/v1/functional/overload.hpp)

Answer (score 8):

You don't need anything *too* fancy: just inherit from all the arguments and use *using-declarations* to bring in `operator()` from the base classes. However, in the variadic case, you can't have a pack expansion in a *using-declaration*, so you have to use a recursive approach, like so:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct overload {}; // only used for empty pack

template <class T>
struct overload<T> : private T {
    using T::operator();
};

template <class T1, class T2, class... Ts>
struct overload<T1, T2, Ts...> : private T1, overload<T2, Ts...> {
    using T1::operator();
    using overload<T2, Ts...>::operator();
};
```

Comment: Wow, I actually didn't think this is really do-able. Impressive.

Comment: Better yet, it has a well defined resolution order.

Answer (score 2):

Brian's answer is better, IMHO, but since I worked on it, here's mine:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename... Fns>
struct overload;

template <typename Fn, typename... Fns>
struct overload<Fn, Fns...>
{
    template <typename... T>
    std::result_of_t<Fn(T...)> operator()(T && ... args) const {
        return Fn()(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }

    using next = overload<Fns...>;

    template <typename... T>
    std::result_of_t<next(T...)> operator()(T && ... args) const {
        return next()(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using template specialization:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
template <typename...Args>
struct overload{

};
template <> struct overload<int>{
    int operator()(int x) const { return x + 1; }
};
template <> struct overload< std::string>{
    std::string operator()(const std::string& s) const { return s + s; }
};
template <typename...Args >
auto f(Args...arg){
    overload<Args...> func;
    return func(arg...);
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << f(3) << std::endl << f(std::string("Hello"));    
}
```

Note: two answers by @Brian and @md5i more general  and elegant and perfect and better than this.